Все дети рождаются с огромным количеством клеток мозга (— или ,) нейронов. Тире или запятая?

Все дети рождаются с огромным количеством клеток мозга (— или ,)
нейронов.

Тире или запятая?

Нашла в одном из ответов, что при обособлении приложений вместо запятой употребляется тире:

если перед приложением можно вставить слова а именно (без изменения смысла): В дальнем углу светилось жёлтое пятно — огонь квартиры Серафимы (Ж. Г.); Она зарисовала древние светильники с гербом города Ольвии — орлом, парящим над дельфинами (Пауст.); На суховатом лице Нечаева, с мягким мальчишеским лбом, остались следы ожогов — два белых незагорающих пятна (Н. Чук.);



перед распространенным или одиночным приложением, стоящим в конце предложения, если подчеркивается самостоятельность приложения либо дается разъяснение:Я не слишком люблю это дерево — осину (Т.) Д.Э.Розенталь. Обособленные приложения


Стилистически предложение кривое. Мозг бывает разный, бывает спинной, "клеток мозга", тут - не понятно, потому что мозговые нейроны или нервные клетки. Вот так это может выглядеть: "К трем годам объем мозга ребенка составляет уже 80% от мозга взрослого человека. Увеличение объема мозга происходит за счет особых глиальных клеток: они необходимы для существования нейронов. Начиная с трех лет, начинается резкое торможение в темпах мозгового развития, а после шести лет оно практически полностью замедляется и заканчивается формирование. "

(головной) мозг новорождённого состоит из огромного количества (нервных) клеток - нейронов. То есть, если тезис вынесен в начало, тут нет таких непоняток, про какой мозг идёт речь, а также "мозг" и "клетки" разнесены. А если дети-рождаются-с клетками мозга - это странно, типа они могут без клеток мозга родиться или что? Не ясно утверждение рождения через клетки мозга и их количество...

Действительно, как верно отметил Буратино, предложение стилистически неверное.
Но отбрасывать смысл и исходить из грамматической структуры, то здесь приложения. Здесь однородные члены предложения, соединённые союзом или.

Я имела в виду тире или запятая. Само предложение без союза.

Все дети рождаются с огромным количеством клеток головного мозга — ​нейронов. Все дети рождаются с огромным количеством клеток головного мозга, ​нейронов.

А-а, ясно. Мы не так вас поняли.

@Буратино  То-то я смотрю, маленькие дети намного умнее взрослых, а как любят учиться и познавать мир. Куда только что девается) Тогда получается, что сколько нейронов получил из небесной кладовой,  тем и располагаешь, увеличить нельзя?

@Sharon не совсем ,до 3 лет мозг растёт, но развивается до 6-7 физически. У детей память лучше на детали, потому что много свободного места, у взрослых начинает соединяться сложным образом, или работают те отделы, которые чаще востребованы. Ну и кроме памяти там есть отделы тоже всякие, разные этапы развития есть. Но в основном мозг растёт до 6-7 лет, а потом физически новые нейроны не появляются, только дохнут, перестраиваются нейронные связи. А дохнуть нейроны могут, ну из-за стресса или из-за алкоголя и тп. Когда кровь перестаёт питать достаточно, тогда быстро мрут.

Когда склероз - проблемы с сосудами, память начинает отказывать, потому что питания не хватает. Ещё всякие Альцгеймеры бывают, особенно у людей которые делают одно и тоже, потому что даже, если пол мозга живо, его можно перестроить, но этим нужно заниматься - изучать слова, делать что-то новое необычное, новый опыт получать, менять использование рук - правую и левую и тп.

Правильный выбор знака (без учета стиля):
Все дети рождаются с огромным количеством нервных клеток мозга, или нейронов.
Сравнить: Все дети рождаются с огромным количеством нервных клеток мозга — нейронов.
Пояснение

При наличии пояснительного союза ИЛИ обособление запятой, тире ставится при бессоюзной связи.

Тема рассмотрена у Розенталя:  § 23. Пояснительные конструкции.


Пояснительные члены предложения могут присоединяться союзом ИЛИ (‘то есть’): Из лесного оврага неслось воркованье диких голубей, или горлинок.
При отсутствии пояснительного союза вместо запятой перед пояснительным членом предложения часто ставится тире: Было ещё одно препятствие на пути учёных — суеверие островитян.
ИНФОРМАЦИЯ (нейроны, или нервные клетки мозга)
Нейроны — это то, что позволяет нам воспринимать окружающий 
мир и взаимодействовать с ним, а также отвечают за все наши 
мысли, движения, эмоции и желания. Во внешнем строении 
нервной клетки выделяют тело (сому) нейрона и отростки 
разной длины (нейриты). 

Термин «нейрон» для обозначения нервных клеток введён Г. В. 
Вальдейером в 1891 году. Впервые нейроны были обнаружены в 
1837 году Яном Пуркине при изучении клеток мозжечка.

О количестве нейронов  (разные мнения). Подсчитать «вручную» 
численность клеток в головном мозге также сложно, как узнать 
количество звезд на небе. Аккуратные подсчеты 
показали, что нейронов и клеток нейроглии в мозге 
поровну, примерно по 85-100 миллиардов. 

Другие мнения. 
Нейроны составляют лишь 25 % от всех клеток мозга, 
остальные 75 % клеток относятся к нейроглии (греч. 
glia —  клей). Нервные клетки в составе головного 
мозга занимают порядка 10  процентов, остальные 90 
процентов это астроциты и глиальные клетки, но их 
задача заключается лишь в обслуживании нейронов. 

Ученые придумали разные способы для определения 
количества нейронов у человека. Рассчитывается число 
нервных клеток на небольшой части мозга, а затем, 
количество умножается пропорционально полному 
объему. Исследователи исходят из постулата о том, 
что нейроны равномерно распределены в нашем мозге.


Шарон, нейрон это и есть клетка. Поэтому писать... рождаются с клетками или нейронами не совмем верно.

Почему? Нервные клетки, или, иначе говоря, нейроны. Это пояснительный, а не разделительный союз. Надо написать:  Все дети рождаются с огромным количеством нервных клеток мозга, или  нейронов.

Да. Но здесь клетка — родовое название. О нервных клетках ничего не говорится.

В тексте надо поправить: не просто клетки, а нервные клетки.  Ведь речь идет именно о них. а не о клетках вообще.

Друзья, большое спасибо за помощь! Склоняюсь написать так: Мы все рождаемся со значительным запасом нервных клеток — нейронов.

Это надо с @Буратино посоветоваться...)
